# Allocating pointers from existing shared memory region - POSIX C API

Tags: c, posix, ipc, shared-memory

I have a structure A of the form described below. My goal is to create the structure in one process and share it across to a different process. A->buffer depends upon user_size and value provided and hence I cannot have a pre-allocated buffer. Knowing that sharing pointers with shared memory is hard across processes since pointer value in one process will no longer be valid in the other process, I tried the following approach.

I wanted to allocate the buffer from shared memory, from the writing process so that other processes can map to the same shared memory and obtain a valid pointer address to the shared memory.

Conceptually, calling mmap on the same shared memory fd descriptor should point to the same location in shared memory, however on the reading process, I'm able to get a valid pointer and valid another_value.

Can someone clarify this? Parts of the code below.

```
struct A {

 int another_variable;
 void *buffer;
}

/* the size (in bytes) of shared memory object */
const int SIZE = 4096;

/* name of the shared memory object */
const char *name = "OS";

/* shared memory file descriptor */
int shm_fd;

/* create the shared memory object */
shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

/* configure the size of the shared memory object */
ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);

a_data = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*A), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
        shm_fd, 0);


if (a_data == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf("ERROR: mmap failed for a_data\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

a_data->buffer = mmap(NULL, user_size,  PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED , shm_fd, 0);

if (a_data->buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf("ERROR: mmap failed for a_data buffer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memcpy(a_data->buffer, "test", strlen("test"));
```

Comment: The memory is shared, but they have different addresses in each process. You can't share the pointer to them.

Comment: Agreed. Is there a way to allocate the pointer from a region in the shared memory. In the example above I would like to know if I can use the same shared memory used by the structure containing the pointer. Otherwise, I will have to allocate from a new shared memory region for every pointer.

Comment: Use a flexible array member and put the array at the end of the struct, rather than using a pointer.

Comment: When you say flexible, do you mean to have an array like buffer[MAX_SIZE] but later use it based on the user's input for user_size? Also, can I understand why you would want me to place the array at the end of the structure if it will be of a fixed size?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: I didn't realize it was always a fixed size, since you're trying to allocate it dynamically. In that case you can just use an array at the end of the structure.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I will look into this. I had more pointers in the structure besides the buffer so I switched my pointers to variables and mapped buffer to a second shared memory.